# PHP urlencode() and whitespace

Tags: php, urlencode

I have this string to be encoded (with line break)

Sender ID
Sender ID
Sender ID

When using this [urlencode generator](http://www.crypo.com/eng_urle.php), I get the desired output which is

```
Sender%20ID%0ASender%20ID%0ASender%20ID
```

However when i using php urlencode() i get this output

```
Sender+ID%0D%0ASender+ID%0D%0ASender+ID
```

When using the php rawurlencode() i get this output

```
Sender%20ID%0D%0ASender%20ID%0D%0ASender%20ID
```

How to achieve the output same as the generator? I need it to be same since Blackberry phone will properly show line break only if the urlencode for line break is **%0A** (i am working on a sms system).

Right now the only solution i can think is to search for the %0D%0A and replace with %0A

Comment: dude, where is your original query string?

Comment: `%0D%0A` is `\r\n`. Do `str_replace("\r\n","\n",$string)`.

Comment: Interesting.  A web search for "CRLF on SMS" indeed shows that CRLF is not recognized in some SMS systems.  Who'd have thought?  (Not that I use Windows....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a Windows line ending which is being translated directly by PHP and ignored by your generator tool. The easy way to get rid of it is to simply:

```
str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $input );
```

`%0D` refers to the 13th ASCII character: `\r`. Since this is immediately followed by `%0A` (the `\n`) it is clear that you have the MS line ending (`\r\n`) instead of the *nix line ending (`\n`) and that the urlencode generator is using the *nix approach.