# PHP. How to remove a %0D character from my code

Tags: php, rss

I am trying to send me an email with a daily digest of some RSS feeds. I receive the following error, caused by an extra %0D character. Could you suggest me what I need to correct in the code to remove it?

Thanks a lot

The error is: simplexml_load_file(https://hdblog.it/feed%0D): failed to open stream: Invalid redirect URL!

```
// Set the timezone to Rome, Italy
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

// Set the cutoff time to 24 hours ago
$cutoff_time = time() - (24 * 60 * 60);

// Set the subject of the email
$subject = "Digest RSS " . date("d/m/Y");

// Initialize the message
$message = "<html><body>";
$message .= "<h1>RSS Digest</h1>";
$message .= "<p>Ecco gli ultimi aggiornamenti dai tuoi feed RSS:</p>";

// Read the list of RSS feeds from a file
$rss_feeds_file = file_get_contents('rss_feeds.txt');
$rss_feeds = explode("\n", $rss_feeds_file);

// Loop through the list of RSS feeds
foreach ($rss_feeds as $rss_feed) {
  // Load the RSS feed
  $rss = simplexml_load_file($rss_feed);
  if ($rss) {
    // Initialize a flag to keep track of whether there are feed items to include in the email
    $items_included = false;

    // Add the feed title to the message
    $message .= "<h2>" . $rss->channel->title . "</h2>";
    // Add a list of items to the message
    $message .= "<ul>";

    // Loop through the feed items
    foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
      // Check if the item was published within the last 24 hours
      $item_time = strtotime($item->pubDate);
      if ($item_time > $cutoff_time) {
        // If it was, add the feed item to the email
        $message .= "<li><a href='" . $item->link . "'>" . $item->title . "</a><br />";
        $message .= strip_tags($item->description) . "</li>";
        $items_included = true;
      }
    }
    $message .= "</ul>";
  }
}

$message .= "</body></html>";
```

I am trying to send me an email with a daily digest of some RSS feeds. I receive the following error, caused by an extra %0D character. Could you suggest me what I need to correct in the code to remove it?

Thanks a lot

The error is: simplexml_load_file(https://hdblog.it/feed%0D): failed to open stream: Invalid redirect URL!

Comment: This error seems to indicate that the file name to open is incorrect.
The `$rss_feed` variable which should contain the filename only contains one character 13...? A newline character.

Comment: I searched for "*php "%0D"*" and turned up quite a few answers. [Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315491/php-urlencode-and-whitespace). The specifics of the problem are different but the root cause - and more importanly the solution - are likely the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP urlencode() and whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315491/php-urlencode-and-whitespace)

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on Windows?

%0D is the carriage return character. You are exploding the input file on `\n` (line feed), but perhaps your input file has `\r\n` line terminators. Try exploding on `'\r\n'` instead.

If your input file has been created on the same platform as you are running your code you could try using the php constant `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code is running on a shared hosting. Using \r\n fixed the problem :)